# SomeActivity.java automatically finish, killed or returned back to previous Activity without touch

Tags: java, android, android-studio

**Dear Expert**, I'am dealing with one problem since few days. I searched for solution but found nothing so I'm here with you. Hope you will help and thanks in advance...

**Question:** I have an ABC App trying to update with API level 33(Android 13) Everything goes fine but e.g.- I open app-> click button to launch new Activity.java-> launched success but **PROBLEM** comes here ! The Activity close automatically after 2/3/4 seconds without error or without touching my phone but if again I open same Activity then it remain open until I close it.

**Few Things Appear in Logcat before close Activity:**
*This Activity Do Nothing unless I try to do so*

```
DEBUG: elapsed 2 / 6
2023-03-27 20:58:20.352 24711-24763 FA                      com.my.package        V  Recording user engagement, ms: 4262
2023-03-27 20:58:20.390 24711-24711 DynamiteModule          com.my.package         I  Considering local module com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite:230500000
2023-03-27 20:58:20.390 24711-24711 DynamiteModule          com.my.package        I  Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite, version >= 230500000
2023-03-27 20:58:20.390 24711-24711 DynamiteModule          com.my.package         V  Dynamite loader version >= 2, using loadModule2NoCrashUtils
2023-03-27 20:58:20.396 24711-24711 Ads                     com.my.package         I  Use RequestConfiguration.Builder().setTestDeviceIds(Arrays.asList("333C8AE82F2C89B0AF4DCBD658E0F35C")) to get test ads on this device.
2023-03-27 20:58:20.401 24711-24763 FA                      com.my.package         V  Activity paused, time: 2548080784
2023-03-27 20:58:20.401 24711-24763 FA                      com.my.package         V  Activity resumed, time: 2548080807
2023-03-27 20:58:20.406 24711-25006 AudioManager            com.my.package         I  In isSpeakerphoneOn(), calling application: # Enables namespacing of each library's R class so that its R class includes only the
# resources declared in the library itself and none from the library's dependencies,
# thereby reducing the size of the R class for that library
2023-03-27 20:58:20.419 24711-24711 DecorView[]             com.my.package         D  onWindowFocusChanged hasWindowFocus false
2023-03-27 20:58:20.435 24711-25183 Ads                     com.my.package         W  Not retrying to fetch app settings
2023-03-27 20:58:20.460  3263-3714  ActivityManagerWrapper  com.miui.home                        E  getRecentTasks: taskId=5899   userId=0   baseIntent=Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=# Enables namespacing of each library's R class so that its R class includes only the
# resources declared in the library itself and none from the library's dependencies,
# thereby reducing the size of the R class for that library/.activities.ActivitySplash }
2023-03-27 20:58:20.521 24711-24711 DecorView[]             com.my.package         D  onWindowFocusChanged hasWindowFocus true
2023-03-27 20:58:20.538 24711-24711 RecyclerView            com.my.package         W  No adapter attached; skipping layout
2023-03-27 20:58:21.265 24711-25240 BufferPoolAccessor2.0   com.my.package         D  bufferpool2 0xb40000789c40d628 : 5(40960 size) total buffers - 0(0 size) used buffers - 21/27 (recycle/alloc) - 10/27 (fetch/transfer)
2023-03-27 20:58:21.265 24711-25240 BufferPoolAccessor2.0   com.my.package         D  bufferpool2 0xb4000079959dc428 : 5(40960 size) total buffers - 0(0 size) used buffers - 15/20 (recycle/alloc) - 7/20 (fetch/transfer)
2023-03-27 20:58:21.265 24711-25240 BufferPoolAccessor2.0   com.my.package         D  evictor expired: 2, evicted: 2
2023-03-27 20:58:21.909 24711-24711 Ads                     com.my.package         W  GET LOCATION COMPILED
2023-03-27 20:58:21.980 24711-24711 ExoPlayerImpl           com.my.package         I  Init 43758ef [AndroidXMedia3/1.0.0-beta03] [curtana, Redmi Note 9 Pro, Xiaomi, 31]
2023-03-27 20:58:21.991 24711-24711 Ads                     com.my.package         I  ExoPlayerAdapter initialized.
2023-03-27 20:58:22.287 24711-25340 DMCodecAdapterFactory   com.my.package         I  Creating an asynchronous MediaCodec adapter for track type audio
2023-03-27 20:58:22.289 24711-25349 CCodec                  com.my.package         D  allocate(c2.android.aac.decoder)
2023-03-27 20:58:22.293 24711-25349 CCodec                  com.my.package         I  Created component [c2.android.aac.decoder]
```

**Android Studio Version: Electric Eel 2022.1.1**

**Manifist**

```
<supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" /> <!-- SET-ALARM -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <!-- WAKE -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID" /> <!-- STORAGE -->
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO" /><!--API 33 for songs-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" /><!--API 33 for albumArt-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM" /><!--API S-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" /><!--API 33-->

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"
        tools:node="remove" /> <!-- THIS QUERIES ONLY FOR YOUTUBE LIVE -->
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.youtube.api.service.START" />
        </intent>
    </queries>
    <queries>
        <package android:name="com.whatsapp" />
        <package android:name="com.whatsapp.w4b" />
    </queries>
<application
        android:name=".activities.MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:resizeableActivity="false"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="false"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.RadioApp"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        tools:targetApi="33">
...
<activity
            android:name=".activities.ActivitySplash"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            tools:ignore="LockedOrientationActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            tools:ignore="LockedOrientationActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

<activity
            android:name=".activities.OpenedActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            tools:ignore="LockedOrientationActivity" />
...
```

**Build.gradle (APP)**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion 33
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.my.package"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode 71
        versionName "4.8.2"
        ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86', 'x86_64'
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            shrinkResources false
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        release {
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    buildTypes.each {
        it.buildConfigField 'String', 'APP_URL', APP_URL
        it.buildConfigField 'String', 'API_KEY', API_KEY
        it.buildConfigField 'String', 'admob_pub_id', admob_pub_id
        it.buildConfigField 'String', 'admob_app_id', admob_app_id
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }

    //    bundle {
//        language {
//            enableSplit = false
//        }
//    }
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    lint {
        disable 'GradleDependency', 'OldTargetApi'
    }
    namespace 'com.my.package'
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'

//    GOOGLE LIBRARY
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.2.3')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:21.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:21.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.1.2'
//for app open ads

    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:2.6.0'
    //Duplicate class found- below solve
    implementation(platform("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-bom:1.8.0"))


    //seekbar and layout library
    implementation 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.4.0'
    implementation 'com.labo.kaji:relativepopupwindow:0.3.1'
    implementation 'com.github.warkiz.widget:indicatorseekbar:2.1.2'

    //ripple click effect library
    implementation 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'
    //Player
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.18.4'
    //image library
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'jp.wasabeef:picasso-transformations:2.4.0'

    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation(platform('com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-bom:5.0.0-alpha.11'))
    implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp")
    implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:5.0.0-alpha.11")

    //shimmer effect library
    implementation 'com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.5.0'

    //multidex library
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'

    implementation 'com.shawnlin:number-picker:2.4.4'

//for equalizer
    implementation 'com.diogobernardino:williamchart:2.2'//don't change to higher

    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.2.0'

    implementation 'com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer:core:11.1.0'

    //implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.5.1'
    // animation
    implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:6.0.0'

//    TabLayout
    implementation 'com.github.Andy671:Dachshund-Tab-Layout:v0.3.3'

    //implementation 'com.github.droidbond:LoadingButton:0.1.5'
    implementation 'com.zeugmasolutions.localehelper:locale-helper-android:1.5.1'
    //local storage
    implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.5.0'
    annotationProcessor 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.5.0'
    implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:20030203.000550'

}
```

**build.gradle (project)**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Application**

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    public MyApplication() {}

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        try {
            SharedPref.init(this);
            AdsManager.initializeAd(this);
            MobileAds.initialize(this, initializationStatus -> {
            });
            Setting setting = SharedPref.get().getSettingModel();
            if (setting != null){
                if (setting.show_open.equals(Constant.ACTIVE)){
                    new AppOpenManager(this, this.getString(R.string.admob_open_ads));
                }
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            //
        }
        try {
            SharedPref.get().setDarkMode(SharedPref.get().isDarkModeOn());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //
        }
        FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);
        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("Hello");
    }

}
```

**Please help, Big Thanks**

**I've Tried:**

- Opening another Activity -> Same problem
- Unistal/ReInstall App -> Same p.
- Using Emulator/ Real device -> Same p.
- Removed Admob ads from Opened Activity -> Same p.
- And few things more...

**Update-1**
This line appear in red color even ActivitySplash.java already finished

```
getRecentTasks: taskId=5942   userId=0   baseIntent=Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.my.package/.activities.ActivitySplash }
```

**ActivitySplash.java**

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
        setWindowFlag(this, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS, false);
        getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        DataParser.fetchSettingData(ActivitySplash.this, () -> {
            SharedPref.get().getFcmToken();
            notificationOpenHandler();
        });
    }


    public void notificationOpenHandler() {
        try {
            if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
                new Handler().postDelayed(() -> {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(ActivitySplash.this, MainActivity.class);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    intent.putExtra(Constant.FCM_TITLE, getIntent().getStringExtra(Constant.FCM_TITLE));
                    intent.putExtra(Constant.FCM_LINK, getIntent().getStringExtra(Constant.FCM_LINK));
                    intent.putExtra(Constant.FCM_BROWSER, getIntent().getIntExtra(Constant.FCM_BROWSER, 0));
                    intent.putExtra(Constant.FCM_IMAGE, getIntent().getStringExtra(Constant.FCM_IMAGE));
                    intent.putExtra(Constant.FCM_EXTRA, getIntent().getStringExtra(Constant.FCM_EXTRA));
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
                }, Constant.SPLASH_TIME);
            } else {
                moveToNext();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            moveToNext();
        }
    }

    private void moveToNext() {
        new Handler().postDelayed(() -> {
            Intent intent = new Intent(ActivitySplash.this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
        }, Constant.SPLASH_TIME);
    }

    public static void setWindowFlag(Activity activity, final int bits, boolean on) {
        Window win = activity.getWindow();
        WindowManager.LayoutParams winParams = win.getAttributes();
        if (on) {
            winParams.flags |= bits;
        } else {
            winParams.flags &= ~bits;
        }
        win.setAttributes(winParams);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it fine with api < 33 ?

Comment: Yes it was fine in previous version of app. This version has same issue with all api, but I have modified many things in my app so Im not able to find the actual case.
**can you please, check my updated Q. at the bottom**

Comment: **Second Attempt**
While I comment SplashActivity and make MainActivity as Launcher Activity then the problem disappear. !!! it means something wrong with the Splach Activity

Comment: Suggest you rollback your changes one by one to determine which was the breaking change that caused the issue

Answer (score 1):

**FINALLY** found the solution. There was 2 issues 1. OnConfigrationChanged by lifecycle while using appOpenAds. 2. Synchronized background data with server, once finished recreated baseActivity. Anyway thanks dear